# How do I create a array of LinkedLists and initialize all of them to an empty string?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to create an string array of linked lists in java. Then initialize everything inside the array to an empty string. Currently, they are all initialized with `null` because of the constructor. This causes a `NullPointerException` when I use an `equals()` method on the contents of the array. So I want to initialize them all to an empty string instead. How would I do this?

```
    private LinkedList<String>[] table;

    public Hashtable (int capacity, String hashFn) {
        table = new LinkedList[capacity]
        hashFn = hashFn;
    }
```

Comment: I imagine you would get more responses if you added what language you were working in to the post, or at least the tags.

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to loop over and set each item to an empty string, like this...

```
private LinkedList<String>[] table;

public Hashtable (int capacity, String hashFn) {
  table = new LinkedList[capacity];
  String emptyString = "";
  for (int i=0;i<capacity,i++){
    table.add(emptyString);
    }
  }
```

I've never tried to do what you want to do, but I couldn't find any quick method to do it.

Of course, if you make it a `String[] array` rather than a `LinkedList<String>[] array`, you can simply call `java.util.Arrays.fill(array,"");`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly then in my opinion the better thing to do would be  to use `.equals()` like following to avoid `NPE`, if you want to compare `String` from your `LinkedList` with any given String:

```
if("givenString".equals(strObjFromLinkedList)) {
        //Do what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer is that the `Collections` class provides an `nCopies` method that you could use something like this:

```
    List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>(Collections.nCopies(capacity, ""));
```

to avoid writing an explicit `for` loop.  A `for` loop would be more efficient though.

---

But what I really want to say is that `LinkedList` is a BAD choice for implementing the primary hash table.  Operations like `get(int)` and `set(int, T)` are `O(N)` for a linked list.  You should be using an `ArrayList<String>`, or better still a `String[]`. These have `O(1)` operations for getting and setting an element.  On top of that, they use significantly less memory.

In addition, you would be better of doing an explicit test for `null` than filling with empty strings.  In reality, the JVM is likely to perform that null test behind the seens anyway.  By doing it yourself, you 1) avoid the comparison with an empty string, and 2) save on the initialization time.

There is more than one way to fix an NPE problem ...